# Adding a row QTWidgetItem to an (inherited) QTableWidget doesn't show any values in the cells

Tags: python, qt

The following code almost works in that the output looks correct, but the actual GUI Widget is not showing any items.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = data
        self.setmydata()

    def setmydata(self):

        horHeaders = []
        for idx, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data)):
            horHeaders.append(key)

        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

    def addrow(self, triangleObject):
        print 'addrow called'
        rowNum = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowNum)

        i = 1
        for val in triangleObject.triangle:
            print rowNum, i, val
            self.setItem(rowNum, i, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(val))
            i += 1

        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

class Triangle(Observer):
    def __init__(self, slist):
        self.ptr = 0
        self.triangle = {}
        self.order = {}

        loopCount = 0
        for s in slist:
            sindex = sIndexHash[s]
            self.triangle[sindex] = (sindex, 0, 0, 0, 0)            
            self.order[loopCount] = sindex
            loopCount = loopCount + 1

data = {'S1' , 'S2', 'S3'}  # the column names
table = MyTable(data, 0, 3) # create an initial table with just column headers no rows

Triangle one
Triangle two
Triangle three
Triangle four
Triangle five
Triangle six
Triangle seven
Triangle eight

table.addrow(one)
table.addrow(two)
table.addrow(three)
table.addrow(four)
table.addrow(five)
table.addrow(six)
table.addrow(seven)
table.addrow(eight)
```

I can see the following output. I can also see a widget that looks like a little spreadsheet on the screen with the correct column names. **But I don't see anything inside the little table widget cells?**

```
addrow called
0 1 1
0 2 4
0 3 7
addrow called
1 1 2
1 2 3
1 3 7
addrow called
2 1 4
2 2 5
2 3 6
addrow called
3 1 8
3 2 0
3 3 5
addrow called
4 1 8
4 2 3
4 3 6
addrow called
5 1 0
5 2 3
5 3 4
addrow called
6 1 9
6 2 10
6 3 3
addrow called
7 1 0
7 2 1
7 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to say

```
self.setItem(rowNum, i, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(val)))
```